# How to protect bistable latching 2 coil relay with diodes?

Tags: relay, dc, diodes, coil

I know that a revers diode is required to protect a DC coil relay.

But to protect this relay [RT314F05](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0da1/0900766b80da1b9b.pdf)? It has 2 coils, are 2 diodes enough?

Answer (score 3):

A reverse diode does not really protect the relay coil - it protects the rest of the circuit when the relay coil open circuits and the magnetic flux collapses producing a peak voltage that can be many hundreds of volts. If it has two coils then 2 diodes are probably enough. If it has one coil this usually means that reverse voltages may be needed to de-latch it and a slightly more sophisticated circuit is needed - see "Bistable coils - operation" on data sheet front page.

Answer (score 0):

To switch a bistable relay with two coils, two driver Push- or Pull-outputs driver are needed. One coil is used to switch the relay into one position and the other to switch it in the opposite. The protection diodes (or called also free wheeling diodes) are needed to protect the coil driver gainst the high voltage spikes when tourning of a coil. A driving microcontroller uses this two outputs to switch between the two stable stages and need to generated a pulse in software. Different driver configuartion example are shown here: http://ichaus.biz/wp8_whitepaper_en . If a push bottom On/Off driver circuit is needed, then the driving pulses have to be generated by monoflops and discrete driver transistors.